# In WebAPI Breeze implementation, can I avoid exposing Metadata function?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

Opening Metadata function using Breeze via API is actually equivalent of exposing the underlying database schema.

Is there a way to avoid opening up metadata api call? I tried not exposing it as suggested. I got the following error

Query failed Metadata query failed for: /breeze/NorthWind/Metadata; The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

What is the right way of avoiding exposing Breeze Metadata calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to obtaining metadata via an API, there are another couple of approaches you could consider:

1. Load metadata from a script. With this approach, you embed the metadata in a script. After loading the script, the Breeze EntityManager can be initialized using the metadata from the script rather than calling an API. I've found this approach quite useful for unit testing when a dependency on accessing a server is undesirable. See [**Load metadata from script**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/load-metadata-script) for more details.
2. Build metadata with hand-written Javascript code to configure it. You probably wouldn't want to do this for a complex data model that you have already defined in Entity Framework, but it can be useful if that isn't a constraint. See [**Metadata by hand**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) for discussion on this approach.

Once you do have metadata, you can export and import the metadata (such as to the browser's `window.localStorage` area) using `MetadataStore.exportMetadata` and `MetadataStore.importMetadata` respectively.

Comment: From the links provided by @chrisg, I created a sample and hosted it at 
https://github.com/pooran/NorthWind-BreezeJS

I had demoed the Breezejs sample at one of the event and modified it to include this fix

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some sort of metadata for Breeze to work. If you do not want to expose your DB structure, either you have to manually change the metadata generated, or have another layer in between your DB entities and the data classes you want to expose. You can generate the metadata of the intermediate layer by data annotations.

Comment: Metadata won't change quite often. Is there a way I cache the metadata and avoid making calls every time a new request is sent?

Comment: That's a different question. TBH I don't know if `Breeze` caches it anyway